# calculate load time of landing page url when an user clicks on href link in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out load time of landing page url of Ad.
When an user clicks a link/Ad, it goes to landing page abc.com. I want to
know whether this operation is finished or what time it has taken to load.
Is it possible in javascript?

Answer (score -1):

My first thought is to pre-calculate the size of the resources, and when you render the client application, instead of having the direct URLs, you could have a map with URL and it's size. 
You also need the connection speed, which you can calculate initially when the page loads (for instance, you take a small image, calculate the download time and then the transfer rate).

Maybe there's something smarter with GZip compression, since most browsers support it.